# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -85 java alogrithm

Tags: java, encryption, indexoutofboundsexception, xor

I have an  algorithm for an XOR function which I have posted below but I am getting a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -85` error. I'm pretty sure that I took the necessary precautions but it isn't working so I was wondering if anyone could help.

Here is the code:

```
public Crypt(byte[] data, int length, byte[] key) throws IOException
    {
        byte v3, v5, v6;
        int len = length;

        while(len > 0)
        {
                --len;
                v3 = (byte) (key[0] + 1);
                int g = (key[0] + 1 & 0xFF);

                key[0] = v3;
                int a = (key[0] & 0xFF);

                v5 = (byte) (key[4] + key[8 + g]);
                int f = (key[4] + key[8 + g] & 0xFF);

                key[4] = v5;
                int b = (key[4] & 0xFF);

                v6 = key[8 + g];
                int e = (key[8 + g] & 0xFF);

                key[8 + g] = key[8 + f];
                int c = (key[8 + g] & 0xFF);

                key[8 + b] = v6;
                int d = (key[8 + b] & 0xFF);

                data[length - len - 1] ^= key[8 + (byte)(key[8 + b] + key[8 + a] & 0xFF)];

        }

            System.out.println("Packet Data: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(data) + "");
    }
```

The full error is:

> Exception in thread "Thread-3"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -85
>           at Crypt.(Crypt.java:51)
>           at Client.run(Client.java:95)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Line "51" of Crypt.java is:

```
data[length - len - 1] ^= key[8 + (byte)(key[8 + b] + key[8 + a] & 0xFF)];
```

I'm confused as to why I am getting this error because I have used 0xFF and taking the other precautions but yet it is still appearing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Here is the key byte array being used:

```
byte key[] = {
                    (byte) 0x2b, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xda, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x58, (byte) 0x24, (byte) 0x32, (byte) 0x6a, (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x1b, (byte) 0x2c,
                    (byte) 0x6b, (byte) 0x61, (byte) 0x3e, (byte) 0xaf, (byte) 0xec, (byte) 0x31, (byte) 0x60, (byte) 0x38, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x46, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x0c, (byte) 0x2b, (byte) 0xb9, (byte) 0x6e, (byte) 0x2e,
                    (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x5d, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xe8, (byte) 0x64, (byte) 0xe3, (byte) 0x70, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0xdb, (byte) 0x93, (byte) 0xda, (byte) 0xcc, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x18, (byte) 0x22, (byte) 0x5e,
                    (byte) 0xdf, (byte) 0x94, (byte) 0x5a, (byte) 0x4f, (byte) 0x25, (byte) 0xbe, (byte) 0x1d, (byte) 0xb5, (byte) 0x4b, (byte) 0xb4, (byte) 0x17, (byte) 0x8b, (byte) 0xf4, (byte) 0x57, (byte) 0x39, (byte) 0xb3,
                    (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0x63, (byte) 0x7d, (byte) 0x1c, (byte) 0x9f, (byte) 0x7a, (byte) 0xca, (byte) 0x3a, (byte) 0x1e, (byte) 0x65, (byte) 0xa7, (byte) 0x68, (byte) 0xd1, (byte) 0x89, (byte) 0x78,
                    (byte) 0x67, (byte) 0x43, (byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0xb2, (byte) 0x8d, (byte) 0xd9, (byte) 0x8e, (byte) 0x9e, (byte) 0x9c, (byte) 0xc9, (byte) 0xe9, (byte) 0x9b, (byte) 0xb6, (byte) 0xba, (byte) 0x75, (byte) 0x20,
                    (byte) 0x74, (byte) 0xd3, (byte) 0x3f, (byte) 0x88, (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x6d, (byte) 0x41, (byte) 0x62, (byte) 0x2a, (byte) 0xc6, (byte) 0xa2, (byte) 0xc5, (byte) 0x5f, (byte) 0x7b, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0xc4,
                    (byte) 0xf6, (byte) 0x3b, (byte) 0xef, (byte) 0x97, (byte) 0x95, (byte) 0x92, (byte) 0x87, (byte) 0xc7, (byte) 0xf7, (byte) 0x52, (byte) 0x7f, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0xa8, (byte) 0xdc, (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0xd0,
                    (byte) 0xfd, (byte) 0x99, (byte) 0x9d, (byte) 0xe0, (byte) 0x0e, (byte) 0x29, (byte) 0x6c, (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0x83, (byte) 0xd5, (byte) 0xe7, (byte) 0xee, (byte) 0xfa, (byte) 0x59, (byte) 0xa9, (byte) 0x27,
                    (byte) 0x26, (byte) 0xcd, (byte) 0xdd, (byte) 0xae, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x44, (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x47, (byte) 0xe5, (byte) 0xf0, (byte) 0x37, (byte) 0x5b, (byte) 0x13, (byte) 0x4a, (byte) 0x96, (byte) 0x4e,
                    (byte) 0x72, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0x79, (byte) 0xd4, (byte) 0xa4, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0x36, (byte) 0xe6, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0xd7, (byte) 0x28, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0xf9, (byte) 0x2d, (byte) 0xbc, (byte) 0x12,
                    (byte) 0xed, (byte) 0xbf, (byte) 0xad, (byte) 0x48, (byte) 0xce, (byte) 0x84, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0x7c, (byte) 0xfb, (byte) 0x53, (byte) 0xe2, (byte) 0xea, (byte) 0x0d, (byte) 0x14, (byte) 0x1f, (byte) 0x54,
                    (byte) 0xaa, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x23, (byte) 0xf2, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0x4c, (byte) 0x8c, (byte) 0x3d, (byte) 0xbd, (byte) 0xa1, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xb7, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x42, (byte) 0x4d, (byte) 0xa5,
                    (byte) 0x8f, (byte) 0x3c, (byte) 0x85, (byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0x77, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x0a, (byte) 0x1a, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x15, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xc0, (byte) 0xb1, (byte) 0xeb, (byte) 0x5c, (byte) 0x71,
                    (byte) 0xd8, (byte) 0xc2, (byte) 0x8a, (byte) 0x0f, (byte) 0x76, (byte) 0x50, (byte) 0xa0, (byte) 0x19, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0xf5, (byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0x69, (byte) 0xe1, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xd2,
                    (byte) 0xab, (byte) 0xc1, (byte) 0x9a, (byte) 0x51, (byte) 0x6f, (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0xb8, (byte) 0xa3, (byte) 0xd6, (byte) 0xcb, (byte) 0xe4, (byte) 0xcf, (byte) 0x2f, (byte) 0xf8, (byte) 0xbb,
                    (byte) 0x16, (byte) 0x66, (byte) 0xb0, (byte) 0x49, (byte) 0xac, (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0xf1, (byte) 0x7e
                    };
```

Comment: Can you supply a sample `key` please? Are you sure it isn't that that is out of range?

Comment: `byte` can take a value in the range `-128..127`. Are you intending to use an unsigned 8-bit value?

Comment: added it @KenY-N - sorry ;)

Comment: I find your whole code to be very **cryptic**. You have two arrays; but yet you are never using `data.length` or `key.length`to retrieve the actual length of both arrays. Then you have a method parameter **length**; which is then used to init **len**. This is just confusing. Why do you need two things that have the similar names to denote the same thing?! This exception is thrown because you your are computing an index of -85; and for sure, your array does not have less than zero entries. Long story short: de-crypt your code; and ensure that you **really** check for your array bounds.

Comment: I don't follow your logic but your key array contains negative values (any value above 0x7F is negative), so you might not want to use those values as indices of any array.

Comment: @EddyG the length paramater is data.length - it is defined in another script.

Comment: @Eran I can't change the key from what it is so what would I need to do to fix it?

Comment: @ShivamPaw But this is not C. There is no need to pass the around the length of an array. And worse: by having a second variable to carry this information, you just increase the chance of running into exactly such problems!.

Comment: I've just noticed that `(byte)(key[8 + b] + key[8 + a] & 0xFF)` should probably be `(byte)((key[8 + b] + key[8 + a]) & 0xFF)`, but I don't know if that fixes your problem or not...

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but them how will that fix the problem as the problem is related to the key isn't it?

Comment: @KenY-N ok i tried that but it still is giving the same error :s

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, so I can't say how to fix it, but `8 + (byte)(key[8 + b] + key[8 + a] & 0xFF)` must never be negative if you are going to be using it as an index of an array.

Comment: @EddyG the reason for two ints for the data.length because the xor is run byte by byte and they keep it moving from 0 all the way to the end of the data length. Eg for the first one lenght and len is 245. Len has 1 deducted from it at the start of the function thing. So for the line "51" it becomes data[length - len - 1] and that is 0. Then for the next one it is going to be 1 because len has another 1 int removed.

Comment: @Eran yep, i figured that it needs to be positive but I can't figure out what the problem is because I thought I took the precautions for it. Would it help if I posted a sample of the "data" byte array?

Comment: `& 0xFF` does nothing to prevent it from being negative, since you cast it to a byte later, so any value above 127 would become negative.

Comment: Figured it out :D Posting the answer now ;)

Answer (score 0):

The correct code that is now working is the following:

```
public Crypt(byte[] data, byte[] key) throws IOException
    {
        byte v3, v5, v6;
        int length = data.length;
        int len = length;

        while(len > 0)
        {
               --len;
                v3 = (byte) (key[0] + 1);
                int g = (key[0] + 1 & 0xFF);

                key[0] = v3;
                int a = (key[0] & 0xFF);

                v5 = (byte) (key[4] + key[8 + g]);
                int f = (key[4] + key[8 + g] & 0xFF);

                key[4] = v5;
                int b = (key[4] & 0xFF);

                v6 = key[8 + g];
                int e = (key[8 + g] & 0xFF);

                key[8 + g] = key[8 + f];
                int c = (key[8 + g] & 0xFF);

                key[8 + b] = v6;
                int d = (key[8 + b] & 0xFF);

                data[length - len - 1] ^= key[8 + (((byte)(key[8 + b] + key[8 + a])) & 0xFF)];


        }

            System.out.println("Packet Data: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(data) + "");
    }
```

Thank you every for your help.